# Object-oriented Tamagotchi-like program with a GUI

Tags: python, object-oriented, homework, tkinter

I am currently working on a small python project for an undergraduate course in python. The task is to create a [Tamagotchi-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi#Gameplay) program with a GUI. My question is whether my code is Object oriented or not? Here are my classes:

Tamagotchi class

```
class Tamagotchi(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, radie, x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.radie = radie
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

        self.createCircle(x, y, radie, fill="black")

    def createCircle(self, x, y, radie, **kwargs):
        circle = self.create_oval(x-radie,y-radie,x+radie,y+radie,**kwargs)
        return circle

    def updateCircle(self,radie, **kwargs):
        self.delete("all")
        self.radie=radie
        self.createCircle(self.x,self.y,self.radie, fill="black")
```

GUI class

```
class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tamagotchi = Tamagotchi(60,140,125)
        tamagotchi.pack(side=TOP)

        activityList = []

        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(20, 20, 20, 20), font='serif 10')

        sizeLbl = Label(self, text="Storlek: ")
        sizeLbl.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N)

        size = Label(self, text = tamagotchi.radie, foreground="red", font=(None, 15))
        size.grid(row=0,column=3, sticky = S)

        sovaButton = Button(self, text="Sova", command = lambda: self.tamagotchiLogic("sova", activityList, tamagotchi, size))
        sovaButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

        tentaButton = Button(self, text="Tenta", command = lambda: self.tamagotchiLogic("tenta", activityList, tamagotchi, size))
        tentaButton.grid(row=0, column=1)

        festaButton = Button(self, text="Festa", command = lambda: self.tamagotchiLogic("festa", activityList, tamagotchi, size))
        festaButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

        pluggaButton = Button(self, text="Plugga", command = lambda: self.tamagotchiLogic("plugga", activityList, tamagotchi, size))
        pluggaButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.centerWindow()

    def centerWindow(self):
        w = 300
        h = 393

        sw = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.master.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (sw - w) / 2
        y = (sh - h) / 2
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    def tamagotchiLogic(self, activity, activitylist, tamagotchi, sizeLabel):
        activitylist.append(activity)

        end = len(activitylist)
        actString = ''.join(activitylist[end-3:end])

        print(actString)

        growthCombinations = ["pluggasovatenta", "sovatentafesta"]
        declineCombinations = ["festasovatenta","tentapluggaplugga"]
        boredCombinations = ["festafestafetsa","pluggapluggaplugga","sovasovasova","tentatentatenta"]

        if actString in growthCombinations:
            tamagotchi.updateCircle(tamagotchi.radie*1.05, fill="black")

        elif actString in declineCombinations:
            tamagotchi.updateCircle(tamagotchi.radie*0.95, fill="black")

        elif actString in boredCombinations:
            tamagotchi.updateCircle(tamagotchi.radie*(1/sqrt(2)), fill="black")

        sizeLabel.config(text=round(tamagotchi.radie))
```

Main

```
def main():
    root = Tk()

    gui = GUI()
    gui.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is built by using classes and consequently by creating objects(instances) of those classes. In addition you are also utilizing the concept of inheritance to associate multiple classes to each other. 
So yes, your code is OOP.